# How do I fix the subtotal function correctly and can be inserted into the procedure? I have tried to make it but the result is not suitable

Tags: sql, function, transactions, procedure, subtotal

```
CREATE TABLE product(
    codeproduct CHAR(5),
    nameproduct VARCHAR(50),
    unit VARCHAR(20),
    price INT
);

CREATE TABLE producer(
    codeproducer CHAR(5),
    nameproducer VARCHAR(50),
    address VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    province VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE transaction(
    codeproduct CHAR(5),
    codeproducer CHAR(5),
    qty INT
);

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[subtotal](@codeproduct AS CHAR(5)) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @subtotal INT
    SELECT @subtotal = product.price * transaction.qty FROM transaction inner join product 
    ON product.codeproduct=transaction.codeproduct
    WHERE product.codeproduct=@codeproduct
    RETURN @subtotal
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE showdata
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT producer.nameproducer, product.nameproduct, product.unit, transaction.qty,
    product.price, [dbo].[subtotal](product.codeproduct) AS 'subtotal'
    FROM product join transaction on product.codeproduct=transaction.codeproduct
    join producer on producer.codeproducer=transaction.codeproducer
    ORDER BY producer.nameproducer;

END
GO

EXEC showdata
```

Comment: What/Why is it not working?

Comment: it is work, but the value is not suitable, i.e. price = 500, qty = 1, result subtotal = 1000.